# Moved from NY to Florida; do we owe NY State Tax?

Tags: income-tax, non-resident, new-york, florida

We moved from New York to Florida in late June 2021. Bought a house here in May, sold our old house in August. I'm retired; wife works remotely (per diem) for NY firm that took out state income tax (still does). We also taken money from retirement funds. We spent 185 days in Florida. Do we owe NY state tax?

Comment: For the wife's income for sure, you may be considered residents for the full year

Comment: Did you have income from January 1st 2021 until you established Florida residency? That income would be claimed by New York. Plus whatever taxes you owed to the state when you sold the house.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep "*wife works remotely for NY firm*". The linked answer addresses this specific scenario, and it is unique to NY, no other State does that.